# How can I use DATEDIFF() to return rows where it has been more than 24 hours since it was added

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have table with column called `date_added` stored as datetime in MySQL.
I want to return rows where it has been 24 hours or more since it was added to the database.

I'm using the following query. However, it doesn't return what I want it to return.

```
SELECT * FROM campaign WHERE datediff(date_added,NOW())>=1
```

Here's what `date_added` in the Database looks like: `2017-08-15 00:48:31`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
//This code is for SQL
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(HOUR,date_added,NOW()) AS Hours 
FROM campaign  WHERE DATEDIFF(HOUR,date_added,NOW()) >=24
```

As you can see i made the diff by hour

**UPDATED**

Try this one below.

```
SELECT * FROM campaign  
WHERE HOUR(TIMEDIFF(DATE_FORMAT(date_added, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"), DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"))) >= 24
```

I used TimeDiff and used dateformat
and made it to hour.

You can also used this query

```
 SELECT * FROM campaign WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, date_added, NOW()) >= 24
```

Comment: #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'
I think MySQL only supports 2 parameters for DATEIFF()

Comment: sorry my bad, it was SQL only, .  check the updated query below

Comment: sorry i dint not remove the HOUR, I have edited the query below.. you can try it now.

Comment: Returned Nothing.
Perhaps take a look at the what the date_added looks like, I've edited it into the question.

Comment: in that case you need match the format of the two dates in datediff

Comment: Finally, Thank You so much. Spent nearly 3+ hours on this lol.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any kind of "diff".  Either of these will do match rows 'added' more than 24 hours ago.

```
WHERE date_added < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY

WHERE date_added < NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
```

Since `CURDATE()` is midnight this morning, this will catch anything done anytime yesterday or today:

```
WHERE date_added < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```